# JavaScript flooring number to order of magnitude

Tags: javascript

I want to floor any integers `>= 10` according to its order of magnitude. For instance,

```
15 -> 10
600 -> 100
8,547 -> 1,000
32,123 -> 10,000
3,218,748 -> 1,000,000
544,221,323,211 -> 100,000,000,000
....
```

I was thinking parsing the `int` to `string` and count how many digits are there, then set the new string to `1` + a bunch of zeros and convert back to number.

```
function convert(n) {
    nStr = n.toString();
    nLen = nStr.length;
    newStr = "1" + Array(nLen).join("0");
    return parseInt(newStr);
}
```

Is there a more mathematical way to do this? I want to avoid converting between `int` and `str` because it might waste a lot of memory and disk space when `n` is huge and if I want to run this function a million times.

Comment: `log10(x)` then round down then `pow(10, x)`?

Comment: `Math.pow(10, Math.round(Math.log10(my_number)) - 1)`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

So you're looking for the order of magnitude.

```
function convert(n) {
    var order = Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.LN10
                       + 0.000000001); // because float math sucks like that
    return Math.pow(10,order);
}
```

Simple ^_^ Math is awesome! Floating point imprecisions, however, are not. Note that this won't be completely accurate in certain edge cases, but it will do its best.

Comment: Should I do `Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.LN10);` instead of `Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.LN10);`?

Comment: Whoops, yes you should XD

Comment: The math in the answer is sound but the math in javascript isn't unfortunately. The convert function fails when n = 1000 and returns 100. :( http://repl.it/4NK/2

Comment: as @TimSanteford said, this answer is incomplete without addressing floating point division issues

Comment: @FactorMystic I have edited the answer to include an epsilon. Is this better?

Comment: Thank you for this! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Math.log(n) will return NaN for negative numbers, so maybe want to add a Math.abs() around n

Comment: the `order` value (before the power of 10 is calculated) is interesting too

Comment: Using `Math.log10(n)` avoids the floating point issue.